# facebook api unicode character in google chrome and IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, unicode

I am trying to create a facebook application (just learning) which will show unicode character. So I write this code:

```
<?php 
    $json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/Answersge');
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    echo $data['company_overview'];     
?>
```

This code was suppose to render like this:

`იპოვეთ პასუხი ნებისმიერ კითხვაზე!` Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJfKU.png

And it work as expected in firefox. But in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer is shows some thing like this:

`áƒ˜áƒžáƒáƒ•áƒ”áƒ— áƒžáƒáƒ¡áƒ£áƒ®áƒ˜ áƒœáƒ”áƒ‘áƒ˜áƒ¡áƒ›áƒ˜áƒ”áƒ  áƒ™áƒ˜áƒ—áƒ®áƒ•áƒáƒ–áƒ”!`

which is of course wrong. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: What do your headers look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following tag before the `title` element:

```
<meta charset=utf-8>
```

You’re getting the data as utf-8 encoded and need to declare it as such. Without any declaration, browsers make a guess.